# unable to track flow of file excution in batch scipt

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
`@ECHO OFF

SET logfile="D:\timer.txt"
SET accessfile="Dashboard.txt"
ECHO "***********************************************************" >> %logfile%
ECHO "Start time %DATE% %Time%" >> %logfile%

if exist D:\2018\%accessfile% goto :labela
if not exist D:\2018\%accessfile% goto :labelb


:labela 
(

Start D:\2018\%accessfile% goto :Runningloop 2>&1 && (

echo "*** Date: %DATE:/=-% and Time: %TIME% :: Dashboard notepad file opened successfully ***" >> %logfile% 

) || ( 
        taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq Dashboard - notepad" /T >> %logfile% 2>&1 && (
        Start  Z:\%accessfile% goto :Runningloop >> %logfile% 2>&1 && echo "*** Date: %DATE:/=-% and Time: %TIME% :: Old instance of file Dashboard is deleted and New instance of file opened successfully ****" >> %logfile%

         ) || (  echo "*** Date: %DATE:/=-% and Time: %TIME% :: Error while closing the current instance of file Dashboard hence unable to Reopen the file   ***" >> %logfile% )


)

:Runningloop
(
CLS

set errorlevel=

tasklist /fi "WindowTitle eq Dashboard - notepad" | find /i "notepad.exe"> NUL

if /i %errorlevel% GTR 0 goto ClosureOfFile

GOTO Runningloop

)
:ClosureOfFile
(
ECHO.

ECHO "Dashbiard notepad file is closed."  >> %logfile%
ECHO "Stop time %DATE% %Time%" >> %logfile%
exit

)

) 
exit /b 


:labelb 
(

echo "*** Date: %DATE:/=-% and Time: %TIME% :: Failure, File does not exist , Please Check *****" >> %logfile%
echo "*** Date: %DATE:/=-% and Time: %TIME% :: End of Script" >> %logfile%
echo "**********************************************************************************************************" >> %logfile%

)
```

`I am trying to open file Dashboard.txt file from batch script, if it already open , I have to close first instance and open fresh one.
if I use loop to track file closure from batch script, taskkill and subsequent commands not working.
if I exclude loop to track file closure , then I don't get correct closing time in log file. 
please suggest , how can I keep loop and execute subsequent commands ?

Comment: below is the code

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code: `Start D:\2018\%accessfile% goto :Runningloop`.  And just because I like to be picky, there is not reason to use the /I option when comparing integers.

Comment: `set errorlevel=` does **not** clear your `%errorlevel%` ! (and isn't necessary at all here, as `find` will *always* set `%errorlevel%` (to `0`, `1` or `2`))

Comment: @Squashman I am trying to open file accessfile and then goto running loop to track its end time

Comment: @ Stephan , that is not the problem

Comment: If you want to run two commands on one line you need to separate the commands with an ampersand.  Regardless of that, the code doesn't make much sense because if the `GOTO` executes the parenthesized conditional code block will never execute.

Comment: ok , then how can I track execution of file that I am opening ? please suggest , as I have to execute parenthesized code + need to check file execution status ?

Comment: any alternative way or something ?